# Couchdb-like http access from a relational database?

Tags: database, http

The new security abilities of couchdb mean you can dispense with your middle-ware and access your data directly from your client *if* you data fits into a key value store.  What if your data needs a relational database?  Is there a relational db with similar abilities?  Should I just tell my db server to listen on port 80?

Comment: To clarify:  web developers will normally have a database to store data, server-side code (php,ruby,Perl) to talk to the db and then client code (HTML, css, JavaScript) that talks to the server via http.  It is now possible to remove the server-side code and talk directly to the db if you are using couchdb.  I want to be able to do the same thing but I need a relational database.

Comment: Matt, you can directly talk to a relational database using native drivers/API's provided by the database. Are you using a ORM technology of some sort ? You seem to be suggesting that you are accessing your data via a HTTP service layer.

Comment: Yes, over http, from a client running on another machine across the Internet.  I have no idea what you mean by "service layer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 10g and Oracle 11g come with an embedded HTTP server.

**edit**

Tim Hall has a succinct overview of the embedded PL/SQL Gateway, which is part of the XML DB implementation in 10g, on his Oracle-Base site.  [Read it here.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_epg_10gR2.php)  In another example he discusses native PL/SQL web services in 11g.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/NativeOracleXmlDbWebServices_11gR1.php).

Comment: Could you clarify what it can do and perhaps point to some documentation?  I am having trouble finding any information about it.

Comment: Thankyou.  That facility probably won't do what I want, but that is hardly your fault!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing, but I will try anyway:

1. A relational database (RDBMS and not embedded) generally has very granular security features which includes login and authentication mechanisms -- the details are beyond the scope of a SO answer.
2. Telling a DB to listen on a certain port doesn't have much to do with security (unless the port is mapped and accepting internet trafic, in which case mapping it away would prevent it to listen for trafic).
3. In a RDBMS the relational the execution environment is your middle man, and a RDBMS will have a back-end storage structure. You generally cannot directly access the underlying engine as the execution environment does a lot of complex things  -- which you cannot hope to co-ordinate with through direct access. The architecture of couch-DB is very simple compared to a RDBMS and places a lot of low-level power in the hands of the developer.

-- edit: after first comment by author --

4. A relational database is meant to be directly accessed -- and layers in the middle are application specific architectural decisions and additions to the RDBMS.

--edit: after second comment by Author --

If you want to access their RDBMS directly via the internet they need make the database port reachable, once that is done you need to use the native drivers/API of  the database vendor.

They may:

1. Open up the database's port to the internet by externally mapping it (bad bad bad).
2. Provide you with an SSH gateway which you could use to tunnel in.
3. provide you with a VPN endpoint to which you can establish a VPN connetion from your network

Comment: See,  most of these things I already know.  I am looking for a way to do something else.